# Regular expression to match anything after dollar sign plus white space

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I had a string like:

```
x123456@server123:/path/to/somewhere$ ls -ltra
```

I want to match anything after `"$ "` (`"$ "` not included. Please, notice the white space.). In this case I would obtein `"*ls -ltra*"`.

My code is:

```
var res = str.match(/\$ (.*)/);
console.log( res[1] );
```

With that I get the expected string... However, is there another way to get that without capturing groups?

Comment: What do you have so far? This is not a free coding service

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Well, that latest edit - *is there another way to get that without capturing groups* - makes the question off topic, I think. **No**, it is not possible.

Comment: @devnull69 are you like a coding cop or what? ;)

Comment: yes of course I am ... thank you for obeying and generously presenting your code :)

Comment: Sory @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez I forgot the question.

Comment: Upvote for presenting the code you have

Comment: Why not `str.split('$ ')[0] || ''`?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel No, it won't work bacause I said anything after `$ ` and if I had something like `x123456@server123:/path/to/somewhere$ touch pepe$pepe` it will fail.

Comment: That's a really good point.

Answer (score 1):

A [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) try in a shell :

```
% nodejs
> var file = 'x123456@server123:/path/to/somewhere$ ls -ltra'
undefined
> file
'x123456@server123:/path/to/somewhere$ ls -ltra'
> var matches = file.match(/\$\s+(.*)/);
undefined
> matches
[ '$ ls -ltra',
  'ls -ltra',
  index: 36,
  input: 'x123456@server123:/path/to/somewhere$ ls -ltra' ]
> matches[1]
'ls -ltra'
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript the resulting **matching group** for any of

```
x123456@server123:/path/to/somewhere$ ls -ltra  
x123456@server123:/path/to/some$$wh$re$ ls -ltra
x123456@server123:/path/to/somewhere$     ls -ltra
// and even:
x123456@server123:/path/to/some$$where$ls -ltra
```

using

```
/(?:\$\s*)([^$]+)$/g
```

would be `ls -ltra`

https://regex101.com/r/dmVSsL/1   <sup>← I could not explain better</sup>

---

You can also use `.split()`

```js
var str = "x123456@server123:/path/to/somewhere$ ls -ltra";
var sfx = str.split(/\$\s+/)[1];

alert(sfx);     // "ls -ltra"
```